# Facebook FB.ui callback response not working on mobile iOS

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api, mobile, callback, fb.ui

I'm working on a Rails app with a Facebook FB.ui "share" button. The callback function uses AJAX to log successful shares to a server-side counter. On any web browser, the share appears on Facebook, the callback function fires with the response, and everything works fine. But on mobile devices (tested on iOS with Chrome and Safari), the share appears on Facebook as expected, but the callback function doesn't receive a response.

I've searched the Facebook docs, but I can't find anything indicating that a FB.ui callback should work differently on mobile devices.

What am I overlooking?

```
    (function() {
      var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
      e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
      document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.facebook_share_button').click(function(){
      FB.ui({

        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Name', 
        description: 'Description.',
        link: 'https://xxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/',

        }, function(response){

          if (response && !response.error_message) {
            $.ajax({
              url : "/log_shares",
              method : "PATCH", 
              data : { shared: 'success' }
            });
            alert("SUCCESS");
          } else {
            alert("ERROR");
          }

        });
      });
    });
```

**UPDATE:** So, without touching the code, oddly, I have had intermittent success with the callback receiving a response. On some tests over the past few hours I've gotten no response, on other tests I've gotten a response but no data, and on others I've actually gotten the data and everything works as expected. But then a few minutes later hitting the same share button doesn't work again.

Sharing from any desktop browser continues to work without any problems at all.

What's going on? Is this something on Facebook's end? Anyone have any experience with Facebook acting spotty on mobile like this?

Comment: are you sure you can log the shares even on desktop? afaik the share callback will get called even if you cancel the popup. unless you authorized the user with publish_actions, in that case you would get the post id. in other words, logging shares is pretty much impossible.

Comment: I haven't authorized publish_actions. As far as I know, the only way to get callbacks on a share without authorization is by using 1) FB.ui for the share button, and 2) by using "method: 'feed'" with it. I have double-checked that logging shares from a desktop browser works (OSX chrome, safari, firefox), and that using a conditional to check for error responses ensures that popup cancelations don't get logged. It's only on an iphone (I haven't tried other mobile devices) that this doesn't seem to work...

Comment: ok, then maybe it just does not work on mobile. in fact, it should not work, it can easily be used for incentivizing shares...you can file a bug though.

Comment: Very strange--it's working intermittently now on mobile. After hitting exactly the same button at different times over a few hours, sometimes a response gets logged, sometimes not. Does seem like a bug on Facebook's end.